# Sidekiq enqueue POST create parameters. Use JSON or ActionController::Parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, performance, redis, sidekiq

I have a model called Order and creating an Order takes a lot of time, so when a User does a POST I want to get those parameters and process them with a background job.

I am using Sidekiq, and I am wondering what would be the best to pass to the perform(..) action, a `.to_json` representation of the parameters passed, or just the ActionController::Parameters type?

Would that matter at all? Knowing that the parameters passed in the request can have more than 10.000 entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the given arguments to `perform_async` will be serialized as JSON. the size of the payload will only affect the memory footprint used and the round trip time to redis. Should not have any other issues with 10K items (unless you would otherwise have problems inserting that long of a string into redis directly).

Internally it takes the arguments and dumps them to json (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/75808b59b8075b2566b448802afcfb9a869e3644/lib/sidekiq/client.rb#L188)